# Setting a One Dimensional Function Equal to a Constant over a Specific Range

Tags: differential-equations, function-construction, variable-definitions

I am trying to take the output from `NDSolve` and create a variable equal to the solution except for a certain range of values. Here is the code I am trying to use but it does not work. Can anyone suggest why it is not working or what I need to do to fix it? I could have sworn it worked at one point and the just stopped working.

`Test = If[0 <= z < ts, BCr[z], Tbl];`

The variables `ts` and `Tbl` are defined constants. `BCr[z]` is found using `NDSolve` all of which are good but the new variable `Test` will not work. I have tried many different variations of this code and nothing seems to work.

Comment: Look up `Piecewise` in [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html).

Comment: What do you mean by "will not work"? What output do you expect, and what do you actually get?

Comment: Your code works for me.  If it does not work for you, `NDSolve` may not be producing an answer. Alternatively, you may have forgotten to define one of your variables. Check for these, correct any errors, restart Mathematica, and run again. By the way, it is not good practice to begin variable names with capital letters.

Comment: NDSolve is producing an answer and everything else is working properly. The result I want is for Test to be equal the solution of BCr from 0<=z<ts and the rest to be equal to a constant value given by Tbl. When I use this code it evaluates without any errors but when I attempt to plot Test it shows no result. I know I got it to work at one point. I have tried many versions of this code I don't understand whats happening to the value of Test when it runs.

Comment: Your code works for me. I believe it would be better in general to define `Test[z_]:=...` but your code works with no modifications.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I found a way to get it to work. I think adding the [z_] would have worked the way I was attempting it but I ended up using a Peicewise function

Answer (score 1):

The assumption is that `BCr[z]` returns a real number.

I will make some fake data:

```
BCr[x_] := x
ts = 1;
Tbl = 1;
```

Now cut and paste your equation

```
Test = If[0 <= z < ts, BCr[z], Tbl];
```

and plot it

```
Plot[Test, {z, -1, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Without changing the result my preference would be to use lower case symbols and make a function out of `Test` using `Piecewise`.

```
bcR[x_] := x
test[x_, ts_, tbl_] := Piecewise[{{bcR[x], 0 <= x < ts }}, tbl]
```

Now plot it as before (`Exclusions-> None` includes the discontinuity at zero.

```
Plot[test[z, 1, 1], {z, -1, 2}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]